# How to recover a Xbox Account?

Tags: xbox-360

I fully deleted my account is there any way to get it back? I need my game of Skyrim back since I deleted it off.

Comment: Sign into the Microsoft account on your xbox. [Instructions](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/profile-move-delete)

Comment: I fully deleted the account.

Comment: You contacted Microsoft to delete the account (which I don't think they actually do?), or you deleted it off your console?

Answer (score 4):

You need to recover your account [per instructions](https://support.xbox.com/en-GB/my-account/manage-gamertag-and-profile/profile-move-delete). If you have closed your Microsoft account, you can [recover it within 60 days of closure](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/my-account/microsoft-account/cancel-microsoft-account). If 60 days have passed since the closure, you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your account still had a gold membership you have until that membership expires to recover your deleted account the 60 day ending period doesn't start until the gold membership expires, because there is no limit to how long an account can be offline.